# Map AVDepthData to RGBA from pixelBuffer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In the iPhone 7plus the captured depth data is not the same size as the captured image. I am interested in mapping the depth data to the color data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I could help you out but your question is not clear enough. What are you trying to do with the AVDepthData? what is your goal

Comment: Thank you @Eyzuky.  I am trying to generate a point cloud based on the depth map generated by the iPhone.  The point cloud will be (hopefully) rendered in VR eg. unity.  Thus far, I have been able to pull the depth map from the camera using AVdepthdata.  However, the depth map is not the same resolution as the captured image.  I was wondering if there is anyway to scale the captured image such its pixels map to the captured depth data.  Basically I would like to add color to the point cloud. I've tried a number of things but have not been successful.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a CIImage?

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a `CIImage`:

```
func depthToCIImage(depthData: AVDepthData) -> CIImage? {

    guard let depthPixelBuffer = depthData.depthDataMap else {return nil}

    return CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: depthPixelBuffer)
}
```

You can use this guide to resize the image:
http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you.  Would you recommend resizing the depth map or resizing the image? Is there a reason why I would want to only resize the depth map?

Comment: What if I tried to downsample the color image to match the resolution of the depth image?  I'm trying to keep the size of the files low :/

Comment: You can save the original depth data and only change its size when needed. This way you don’t have bigger file size saved to disk.